# Max number of devices can GCM send push notifications to

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I was wondering as to what would the limit be for the max number of registered Android devices can gcm send a message to. I know the documentation says that the payload needs to be 4 kb in size, but does that include the list of gcm ids. The size of each gcm id is about 160 bytes, can I send a multicast push notification to only about 20 devices at any point?

Comment: I have done with `100` devices in a single day. now i am not sure about `101`

Comment: You mean, when multicasting? I don't have the link right now, but it should be at most 1000 recipients per POST

Comment: ohh wow, thats great news, let me do some researching on that and will post the link here :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the Official Google Documentation, specifies a list of devices (bases on registration tokens or IDs) receiving a multicast message. It must contain atleast 1 and at most 1000 registration tokens.
For multicast messaging, not for single recipients. Multicast messages (sending to more than 1 registration tokens) are allowed using HTTP JSON format only.

You may check the Official Google documentation here: https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref